# Nullpointerexception getSystemService

Tags: android

Following line will only not result in a nullpointer exception if I'm connected to a WLAN:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Otherwise I get a nullpointer-exception straight ahead? How can I fix this? I want my background service to only work, when it is connected to wlan. But that Nullpointerexception just kills the whole app...

Comment: Are you sure it's this line that throws the exception? It seems more likely that `getSystemService()` would return `null` and then a `NullPointerException` would be thrown when you tried to use `cm`.

Comment: Yup I'm exactly sure. I had the same idea like you. But I double checked the line. And it is exactly this one.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace, perhaps? I'm not familiar with how Android works, but in a normal JVM that line can't throw a `NullPointerException`, if `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` is what it looks like. The `getSystemService()` method might throw such an exception, but then that would show up in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Add to the manifest the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I am late but in case someone is still looking,

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

no need of `Context` in the `getSystemService()` argument.

Comment: [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) says `CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` is a static member of `Context`. Since you omitted it, I guess you've got a static import for it?

Answer (score -2):

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == 1) {
 // CONNECTION_WIFI = true;
}
```